# How to congfigure access rights for consortium members on channel level in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm developing a blockchain solution on Hyperledger Fabric. This solution should be used to provide the interactions bewtween manufacturers and suppliers. I supposed that in this case there should be a single blockchain ledger with information about manufactured goods. This ledger should be used both by manufacturers (to register new goods) and by suppliers (to update goods: for example, mark some item as delivered).

The Hyperledger Fabric official documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/fabric_model.html#privacy) says that the ledger is strictly linked with a channel:

> Blockquote
>   Hyperledger Fabric employs an immutable ledger on a per-channel basis, as well as chaincode that can manipulate and modify the current state of assets.

So I intended to create a single channel and install 2 different chaincodes on:

- chaincode for manufacturers (to register manufactured goods)
- chaincode for suppliers (to mark registered goods as delivered)

But when I prepared a demo application, I revealed, that the second chaincode **cannot** query the items created with the first one (i.e. each chaincode has an isolated ledger).

How can I deploy the ledger, which should be shared between organizations having various roles (access rights), if I don't want to force all of them (manufacturers and suppliers) to install the full chaincode (containing both 'register goods' and 'mark as delivered' operations) on their environment?

Thanks & Regards

Igor Egorov